# Create a Checkerboard of buttons, Lightning Design System

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

I am trying to use the SLDS Grid to create a 'checkerboard' of buttons. I have a single colum of eight buttons. I have perused the documentation but I cannot figure how to specify rows and columns with the grid. I know in swing I was able to say something like 'col 1 row 1'. I think it has something to do with the sizing aspect of slds but that seems hacky to me. Any Help ?

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">

    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry I cant really take a screen shot: heres a link to the preview(hope that works)
 https://bigmax-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/Chess.app

It basically just files the buttons straight down, where I would want them to be in 8 rows and 8 columns. The sizing trick didn't work as I thought it would.

Comment: maybe you can update your post with what your current approach is, html and css whise? [this](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) link on the slds grid system should provide useful.

Comment: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/sizing/#overview I think this is the answer. When using sizing; 1 of X, X is the column 1 is the row, basically. Is this the recommended way ?

Comment: i dont see any rows in your grid, what is the  output? (screenshot)